# ^H in bash variable

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello^H^H"   #hello
echo "hello^H^H "  #hel o
```

I know ^H deletes back a letter in console. But why the first echo has no effect and second one gets "hel o".

Comment: I tried it on my Mac OS X (10.8.4) and it produces correct output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backspace just moves the cursor one position to the right without actually erasing what's printed on the screen. Only your second instruction actually erases the 4<sup>th</sup> character by overwriting it with the trailing space in your string.

I'll try to visualize it:

```
$ echo "hello^H^H"
hello
   ^
   `-- cursor position
$ echo "hello^H^H "
hel o
    ^
    `-- cursor position
```

Comment: Yes this is correct answer. & to add, some terminal emulators replace single `\b` with `\b<space>\b` (where `\b` or `^H` is the backspace character.) so that backspace character actually shows the character erased...

Comment: @anishsane Which terminals do this?

Comment: I had seen it in windows hyper-terminal, used typically for serial-port communication or on serial-over-TCP. Not sure, if it's available on any linux terminal. Maybe, I was wrong in saying "some terminal emulators", because I know only one.

Answer (score 0):

$ echo "hello^H^H"
hello
   ^
   `-- cursor position
$ echo "hello^H^H "
hel o
    ^`
-- cursor position